# Pygame importing from different location

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
Game Folder
  data
    assets
      fonts
      sprites
        player.png
      sounds
        movement.wav
    modules
      sprites.py
      sounds.py
  main.py
```

This is my pygame application directory. I'm importing `sprites.py` and `sounds.py` in `main.py` with:

```
from data.modules.sprites import *
from data.modules.sounds import *
```

In `sprites.py` file, I want to get file with this directory: `Game Folder/data/assets/sprites/player.png` but it can't remove directories. When I try to print directory before the error, it prints:

> pygame.error: Couldn't open 'data/modules/data/assets/sprites/player.png'

I tried `pathlib`, `os`, `sys` modules. How do I move upper directories with any module?

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need the whole directory. for example `C:/Users/user/Documents/Game Folder/data/assets/sprites/player.png`